# How to use setRetainInstance(boolean)?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

Suppose I have a `Fragment A`. It has an instance variable `mViewPager` that points to its `ViewPager`.

In the `onCreate(Bundle)` of `Fragment A`, I invoke `setRetainInstance(true)`.

Upon orientation change:

1. `onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)` is called, and a new view is inflated. So, I have a new `ViewPager` inside the newly inflated view.
2. `mViewPager` points to the original `ViewPager` upon orientation change.

My question is: how do I get the new `ViewPager` in (1) to be associated with the retained `mViewPager` in (2)?

Or should I just use `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`?

Comment: UI elements should be recreated ... you can retain data ... so for the first question is: you can't ... and for the second: what for?

Comment: I ask the second question because if the answer to the first is as you suggested, then I think I need another way to restore the `ViewPager`?

Comment: you don't need a viewpager ... it is not valid after retention ... you just need a data from it ... that's why I'm asking why you need viewPager instance(what you wana achive with this)

Comment: So what you are saying is that I do not need the old `ViewPager`, I just need to retain the data? For data, does it mean the adapter? Or the data behind the adapter?

Comment: *Or the data behind the adapter?* yes, finally we are talking about the same ... now fx in `onPostExecute` set field `List<Items> mDataFromWhichViewPagerWasBuild = somedata; buildAdapterForViewPagerAndSet(somedata);` ... now if fragment retain you can check in onCreateView `if(mDataFromWhichViewPagerWasBuild != null) buildAdapterForViewPagerAndSet(mDataFromWhichViewPagerWasBuild) else new AsynctTaskStartLoading().execute();` ... somethig like this would not load data fx if orientation chaneged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in **@Selvin**'s comment, you should let the UI element to be recreated.

Some information which you should know:

`setRetainInstance(true)` should be used for non-UI Fragment only. And my personal advice would be not to consider this first, unless you are run out of option.

> To properly handle a restart, it is important that your activity
>   restores its previous state through the normal Activity lifecycle, in
>   which Android calls onSaveInstanceState() before it destroys your
>   activity so that you can save data about the application state. You
>   can then restore the state during onCreate() or
>   onRestoreInstanceState().

You are right about using `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`, in general, you should use to save your state. Please be noted that, it is the state you save, but not the UI or the whole Fragment.

For example, a state can be a count on how many times a button is clicked.
Check the link below on how to save state

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#SaveState

Moreover, some UI states, e.g. text inputted in EditText are already handled in the system API. So you only need to handle states you maintained by yourself.

**Edit:**

If you are new to this, and do not know what you need to save and what do not, simply skip it first, and play around orientation change WITHOUT `onSaveInstanceState`. Then you would soon find out what is lost in the process, and that would be the state which you need to keep.

Comment: "setRetainInstance(true) should be used for non-UI Fragment only" - this is very helpful. You have saved me twice!